# auctex forward search in multifile tex with sumatra and arara

Tags: emacs, auctex, arara

Forward inverse search work properly for single-file documents. As for multifile document, I use local file variable to indicate the master `tex` file. When editing in some included document, auctex can correctly compile it and view it using Sumatra. However, the forward search and inverse search do not function as expected. Sumatra always locates the pdf to the last position I viewed. Besides, there is no response for double click in Sumatra with inverse search activated.

I noticed that the view command passed to Sumatra goes as follows:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -forward-search chap3.tex 4  "thesis-main.pdf"
```

Seems no problem. But why doesn't Sumatra go to the right place?
My configuration code for auctex:

```lisp
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
;; (setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
;; use Sumatra PDF to preview pdf
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Sumatra PDF" ("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance"
            (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n ") " %o"))))

(eval-after-load 'tex
  '(progn
     (assq-delete-all 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection)
     (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Sumatra PDF"))
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("Arara" "arara %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t :help "Run Arara."))))
```

My environment of emacs:
windows 10 + emacs24 64bit + Sumatra

<s>Update1:
I tested a simple document of class article which includes a sub document. The forward and backward search work fine, so the problem must be related to my original document. It uses a customized template and some packages. I am struggling to identify which blocks the function of forward and inverse search. Any suggestions?</s>

Update2:
It is about the arara command I used. See my answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I assume you're using the instructions from [Stack Overflow: Sync Emacs AUCTeX with Sumatra PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14629767)?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the instruction there works well for single file document.

Comment: Never saw a link to the other question, so I wasn't sure if it was the same code, or just similar. How about [Is forward search meant to work from an include file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/) instead?

Comment: I think the question you mentioned is different. There, the file variable indicating the master tex is missing. For my question, the file variable has been setted correctly.

Comment: Then a basic two-file [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with a main TeX file, an included TeX file, and minimized AUCTeX configuration may help. I'm not an AUCTeX user any more, but having all the relevant information in one place would help those who are.

Comment: I use a customized document class, i.e., a `.cls` template. I think that is the reason why sync search does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30613/discussion-between-empenguin-and-mike-renfro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use arara, make sure at the last step, turn on synctex.
See [this post](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/arara.html).
Specifically, use

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
```

instead of

```
% arara: pdflatex
```